# Memory Page / Block Implementation in C

Tags: c, linux, performance, memory

I want to replace a Java version of a page management API with a C version. The C version should support almost unlimited space (yeah!) and incredible speed (tm).

I also need a special binary search version but I can do that myself.

The questions are:

- What page size works best?
- Is there a standard framework the C people usually use?
- What is the best size in terms of overhead, OS resources and so on to create those chunks?
- What is best used to access those chunks?
- Is memcpy the best one has in modern CPUs or do I need assembler to squeeze something out?
- Can one align those chunks by the page size so everything starts at an actual physical address of a multiple of page size?
- What about mapping files? Any clue?

Target platforms are mostly Intels Xeon v3 and newer Linux kernels.

[update]

The solution is used to manage up to 1TB memory. The memory will be used for in-memory tables that represent shards of a distributed in-memory database that might span 100TB and more in its final size.

Each Page will be the basic memory block for a part of a column of those tables being either a data column or an index. The pages will use value compression techniques representing integers (fixed point numbers) from one byte up to 8byte per value. This compression is transparent for the column.

The pages will be part of a page pool. The page pool itself is a list of bulk memory parts that group pages together.

-> pagePool ->* pages ->* page.

Now the question is about the addressing scheme. I do not want to spend more than two days on this so I just hoped for a library doing so.

--

The current state of affairs:

The page pool uses value compression itself. Depending on the page size it will feature addresses that are a multiple of page size and as much as roundUp(log256(overallMemory / pageSize)) = numberOfBytes per Address.

So for 4KB pages one would need 32bit page-addresses for 1TB memory.

Since the page pools can grow dynamically and pages can be moved from one location to another in order to compact page space to free blocks of memory a table is used mapping pageIds (in the pagePool) towards the actual addresses in memory.

So this overhead would be 4bytes per 4KB page allocated => 0.1% Overhead

Also the page pool need to keep track if a page is free/deleted and where the first and last free page is along with the number of unused but allocated pages. So two counters will be used and a bit map -> 8 * 3 + pageCount / 8 as additional overhead.

Once the number of free pages exceeds for a certain time the tables might compact by copying one page to another requiring locking mechanism that can reused for other stuff. I have not decided about that yet. So there comes additional overhead.

Using multiple page pools with custom page sizes (but power of two) one can have simple pageIds as pointers to the actual addresses of the page. Once the page is moved the address pointer will change.

The number of page pools used will allow for shorter pageIds. A shard of the search index for instance has a target size of 1GB and once it grows considerable larger it is split in two using fast operations that copy pages but also being able to move pages to a certain part of the pool that is simply assigned to the new pool meaning splitting the pool might result in very few actual page copies.

So a GB with a page size of 4KB results in 2^30 - 2^12 = 2^18 = 3Bytes of pageIds but if the indices are loaded correctly it is likely that 2Bytes are used on average (value compression can work with minimum values storing only the deltas according to the minimum and updating all values the minimum has to change).

Since I mix C and Java all that remains in C are the Page implementation, the PagePools allocation and the address tables. The rest is done using Java.

So basically if there is no support for this and no standard library aiding in this, I have to do it myself right?

Any special remarks how to do this?

Comment: Martin, the bottom line is a C replacement will most likely be orders of magnitude faster than your current java implementation, regardless of page-size, etc.... Your memory scheme will be determined during development. With C, you are working at the direct memory allocation and use level, and you can tailor your memory use exactly as required. You have your entire systems virtual memory available for use and you can use chunks from 1 byte on. (allocations in blocks of powers of 2 is a safe starting point) `memcpy` and `memove` are fine. You can align as needed.

Comment: I'm torn between 'too broad' and 'primarily opinion based' as close reasons (with 'unclear what you are asking' lurking in the wings).  Without information about what this page system is meant to do, and expected usage patterns, and such like, I'd be reluctant to try pontificating.  Also, you need to identify how much memory you expect to have available in total on the system, as well as the workload of other processes on the system, and … well, there is a lot of information needed to come up with a sane answer about sizing questions.  There isn't a standard framework.